# PHP - How to loop through a underscore formatted post data?

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently working on a application where I need to parse the data posted into the server. The data is a underscore-delimited string which indicates which parent are they under.

The data posted to the server looks like this:

```
department: 'Sales'   
s1: 'Logistics'
s1_q1_type: multiple
s1_q1: 'Q 1'
s1_q1_c1: ''
s1_q1_c2: ''
s1_q1_c3: ''
s1_q1_correct_c1: 'on'
s1_q1_correct_c2: 'on'
s1_q1_points: 10
s1_q2_type: multiple
s1_q2: 'Q 2'
s1_q2_c1: ''
s1_q2_c2: ''
s1_q2_points: 10
s2: 'Analysis'
s2_q1_type: multiple
s2_q1: 'Q 1'
s2_q1_c1: ''
s2_q1_c2: ''
s2_q1_correct_c2: 'on'
s2_q1_points: 5
s2_q2_type: multiple
s2_q2: 'Q 2'
s2_q2_c1: ''
s2_q2_c2: ''
s2_q2_points: 15
```

From the code above: s## are "sections", under sections there are q## (questions), then under questions there is: type, points, c## (choices) and correct answer(s). There can be multiple correct answers per question.

I need to parse the above code to an array that looks like this:

```
department: 'Sales',
sections: { 
    s1: {
        title: 'Logistics',
        questions: {
            q1: {
                title: 'Q 1',
                type: multiple,
                choices: {
                    c1: '',
                    c2: '',
                    c3: ''
                },
                correct: {
                    c1: 'on', 
                    c2: 'on'
                },
                points: 10
            }, 
            q2: {
                title: 'Q 2', 
                type: multiple, 
                    c1: '',
                    c2: ''
                points: 10
            }
        }
    },

    s2: {
        title: 'Analysis',
        questions: {
            q1: {
                title: 'Q 1',
                type: multiple,
                choices: {
                    c1: '',
                    c2: '',
                    c3: ''
                }
                correct: {
                    c1: 'on'
                },
                points: 5
            }, 
            q2: {
                title: 'Q 2'
                type: multiple,
                    c1: '',
                    c2: ''
                points: 15
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using foreach and checking if weather the key is isset() but then I'm not getting anywhere.

```
$i = 1;
$array = array();
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){
    if( isset( $post['s' . $i] ) ){
        $array['sections'][$key] = $value;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why this got upvoted but you say you have tried with a foreach. Please post that code so that we have something to start with.

Comment: is the input static or dynamic..because it hard to distinguish betwen c1,c2,c3 with type and points.. unless it static

Comment: where is the code you have tried? you may use explode function with underscrore then loop into the array...

Comment: The inputs are dynamic @Adreas going to update my question, hold on

Comment: Guys, please see updated question

Comment: Hi @Yoshi, the HTML input is a string, not array.

Comment: @Yoshi, it's a Form Data with key value pairs. so I would access the value of "department" like this: $_POST['department'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you looking for..

this is just roughly code.. you can take a look

```
$everyinput = [
    's1'=>'Logistics',
    's1_q1_type'=>'multiple',
    's1_q1'=>'Q 1',
    's1_q1_c1'=>'',
    's1_q1_c2'=>'',
    's1_q1_c3'=>'',
    's1_q1_correct_c1'=> 'on',
    's1_q1_correct_c2'=> 'on',

    's1_q1_points'=>'10',
    's1_q2_type'=>'multiple',
    's1_q2'=>'Q 2',
    's1_q2_c1'=>'',
    's1_q2_c2'=>'',
    's2_q1_correct_c2' =>'on',
    's1_q2_points'=>10,

    's2'=>'Analysis',
    's2_q1_type'=>'multiple',
    's2_q1'=>'Q 1',
    's2_q1_c1'=>'',
    's2_q1_c2'=>'',
    's2_q1_points'=>5,
    's2_q2_type'=>'multiple',
    's2_q2'=>'Q 2',
    's2_q2_c1'=>'',
    's2_q2_c2'=>'',
    's2_q2_points'=>15
];

$head = [];
foreach($everyinput as $key => $input) {
    if ($key[0] == 's') {
        if (strpos($key, "_") !== false) {
            $factor = explode("_", $key);
            if (count($factor) > 2) {
                if ($factor[2] == "type" || $factor[2] == "points") {
                    $head['sections'][$factor[0]]['question'][$factor[1]][$factor[2]] = $input;
                } else if($factor[2] == 'correct') {
                    $head['sections'][$factor[0]]['question'][$factor[1]]['correct'][$factor[3]] = $input;
                } else {
                    $head['sections'][$factor[0]]['question'][$factor[1]]['choices'][$factor[2]] = $input;
                }
            } else {
                $head['sections'][$factor[0]]['question'][$factor[1]]['title'] = $input;
            }
        } else {
            $head['sections'][$key]['title'] = $input;
        }
    } else {
        $head[$key] = $input;
    }
}

dd($head);
```

Result
[image]

Comment: do you mind if I enhance your answer? all credits will always be yours...

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked for me. I am now marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: @ZeroOne I have been playing with your code, I am facing a problem which I cannot solve - I couldn't figure out how to add the "correct" answers. There can be multiple answers to a question. Can you please help me? I've updated the post data in my question above, can you update your answer please?

Comment: You are amazing sir. Thanks!